# Копируются списки

Tags: python, list

Учусь питону. У решаю задачи. При их решении у меня уже 2 раз проблема что я изменяю один список а меняются все. Я новичок поэтому прошу немного разжевать для меня проблему.

Примеры кодов:

```
spisok1 = list()
spisok2 = list()
for _ in range(int(input())):
    spisok1.append(input())
spisok2 = spisok1
for _ in range(int(input())):
    for i in range(int(input())):
        spisok2[i] = spisok1[int(input()) - 1]
    spisok1 = spisok2[:i + 1]
for i in spisok1:
    print(i)
```

Суть этой задачи в том что в ней под наперстки можно класть предметы и тасовать, то есть:

1. Ввод количества предметов и они кладутся под наперстки в том порядке как их записали. 1 наперсток - 1 предмет.
2. сколько раз меняли наперстки
3. В зависимости от пункта 2 столько то раз мы вводим:
   кол-во наперстков (можно меньше написать тогда остальные удалятся)
   и их порядок относительно прошлого например были 1 2 3 а мы можешь написать 3 2 1

если надо скину второй код с такой же ошибкой

Comment: По сути сам код работает без ошибок, но относительно ответа выдается ошибка

Comment: Ответьте на три вопроса: Что вводите? Что выводится? Что должно выводиться с Вашей точки зрения? Добавьте это в свой вопрос.

Comment: `spisok2 = spisok1` это не приведет к копированию списка, просто переменная `spisok2` будет ссылаться на тот же объект, что `spisok1`. Поэтому меняя объект в `spisok1` поменяется и для `spisok2`. Для копии списка сделайте так: `spisok2 = list(spisok1)`

Comment: @gil9red спасибо очень помог! как  отметить что ты правильно ответил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На мой взгляд, копию списка лучше делать в явном виде:

```
spisok2 = spisok1.copy()
```

Такой код ведь сразу понятно, что делает, в отличие от других вариантов копирования списка, которых много на самом деле - и `list(spisok1)`, и `spisok1[:]`, но в них не так очевидно на первый взгляд, что в коде происходит.

Comment: Согласен, так явнее

Answer (score 2):

`spisok2 = spisok1` это не приведет к копированию списка, просто переменная `spisok2` будет ссылаться на тот же объект, что `spisok1`. Поэтому меняя объект в `spisok1` поменяется и для `spisok2`.

Для копии списка сделайте так:

```
spisok2 = list(spisok1)
```

Comment: Добавлю только, что подобное поведение характерно и для других случаев последовательного присваивания. Практически с любым объектом. Нужно очень внимательно использовать подобное присвоение.

Answer (score 2):

Не стоит забывать что есть два способа копирования: поверхностный(описан в других ответах) и глубокое копирование [copy.deepcopy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) - deepcopy не только создает копию объекта, но и рекурсивно создает копии входящих в него объектов.

Так, например в примере ниже видно, что при поверхностных копиях, изменения через spisok2 отражаются и в spisok1, чего не будет в copy.deepcopy

```
dct = {2: 3}
spisok1 = [1, dct]
print(spisok1)  # [1, {2: 3}]

# list
spisok2 = list(spisok1)
spisok2[1][2] = 4
print(spisok1)  # [1, {2: 4}] - список изменился

# copy
spisok2 = spisok1.copy()
spisok2[1][2] = 5
print(spisok1)  # [1, {2: 5}] - список изменился

# срез
spisok2 = spisok1[:]
spisok2[1][2] = 6
print(spisok1)  # [1, {2: 6}] - список изменился

# copy.deepcopy
import copy
spisok2 = copy.deepcopy(spisok1)
spisok2[1][2] = 7
print(spisok1)  # [1, {2: 6}] - список Не изменился
```

Answer (score 0):

Также можно использовать оператор среза

```
list1 = list2[:]
```