# Python 3. Словарь наследуется. Как это работает?

Tags: python-3.x, словарь

Почему словарь "a" изменяется?

```
a = {0: {'type': 'v', 'name': '1'}, 1: {'type': 'v', 'name': '2'}, 2: {'type': 'v', 'name': '3'}, 3: {'type': 'v', 'name': '4'}, 4: {'type': 'd', 'name': 'Доп'}}
b = ['240', '245', '415', '120', '+179']
c = a
for k in range(len(c)):
    c[k]['val'] = b[k]
print(a)
```

Comment: Словарь не наследуется, строкой `c = a` вы создали переменную, которая ссылается на **тот же самый** словарь. Значит значения `c` и `a` будут всегда одинаковыми, потому что они ссылаются на один и тот же объект.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Копируются списки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1208961/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8) Там хоть и про списки, но разницы со словарями нет.

Comment: c = a.copy() - не помог

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался сам. Модуль copy, сделать глубокую копию словаря - `c = copy.deepcopy(a)`.